# Eclipse LogCat not keeping text

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logging, logcat

I am using Eclipse for Android Development.

I am trying to debug my app, the Logcat is running in super fast mode, displaying lots of log, but it does not keeping it, it load and then clear the data and loop....

I am using a real device and I have set the filter for me App

I try to stop to read the log, but it wont, continue to load and clear. I seems like its running out of memory space or something ?

Anyone know how to fix this issue ?

I tried to restart eclipse and so, but no hope.

Comment: are you using real device?

Comment: yes I am . Samsung Note

Comment: try running with emulator or genymotion..still have the same issue or not..i have the same issue while i log my android device, but when i run it on genymotion, i got the log

Comment: Hi thanks. but I cant run emulator. I using a SDK for my video Player. and it only works on real device

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change preferences,
Navigate as

From menu
Window -> preferences -> android -> logcat 
And set "maximum number of  logcat messages to buffer:"

Set 10 time of number

Comment: @Ravi Koradiya I set to 500000, it kind fixed the problem.. but eclipse crash after a while

Comment: It may cause out of memory. You have to increase memory for eclipse from ini file.